# Can I use "the %whatever% one" and particularly "the other one" in IELTS Academic writing?

Tags: writing, formality, ielts

From some source I have heard that **the other one** is informal.
I am considering using this word in the IELTS Academic writing, particularly in the following sentence.

> Overall, both sites offer almost equal extent of accessibility from a city centre, although each of them has its own advantages *over the other one*.

Is this appropriate to use these structures in this type of an essay?

Research conducted before asking:
1. A Google search ("the other one" formal, "the other one" informal, what is informal in ielts essay) gave no relevant answers.
2. SkELL's British corpus has entries of structures "the %word% one".

Comment: Could you say more about it?  I'm not following.  In what contexts is it said to be informal, and who's doing the saying?

Comment: Perhaps you could give an example? I feel it may be a case where it would be rare to need this construction in academic writing, usually you would instead refer to the thing directly, or when contrasting things it will not be necessary to specify "one".

Comment: I agree with what the others have said here: (a) I think "the other one" is too short a term to decide if it's appropriate for academic writing by itself and without any other context; (b) I wonder what source said it was informal, and what reason was given; (c) What did you search for in Google? If you don't tell us what you searched for, then "A search in Google gave nothing" means nothing.

Comment: @J.R., I've added the information that you asked. Unfortunately, I don't remember from which source I've got the information about "the other one" being informal, but I remember that it was some site.

Comment: Ramid, that's helpful information. Thanks for making the update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When making a choice or distinction between two items, we can use **the other one** to refer to the item that is not being presented to us at the moment or that is not under consideration at the moment.

> Would you like to hear that song?
>   --No, I want to hear the other one.
>   What other one?
>   --The one you mentioned a minute ago, about the walrus.
>
> Do you like this car?
>   -- No, I like the other one better.

As the examples show, the phrase relies upon speaker and listener being in sync with one another; "the other one" means "not this one but another which we were speaking about a moment ago. or another that I am looking at and nodding towards right this moment".

Insofar as it relies upon a conversational context, and possibly upon body language, the construction is ill-suited to writing that is not conversational in nature.
.

Comment: Does your answer stay the same after I have added information about my example of using this structure?

Comment: "...each has its advantages over the other" is how you'd typically find it written.

Comment: Thank you. With your answer and comment I have understood that: 1. _the other one_ is not appropriate in formal writing. 2. I have used unsuitable construction in my example.